Tailwind border style with border bottom doesn't work together
When using Tailwind CSS with border-b and a style like border-dashed, the border doesn't get displayed anymore.
I'm using React Native with tailwind.


You should define border color as well.
Try this example https://play.tailwindcss.com/AtpgX2D4gm
If you remove border-black border will not be displayed

I don't think it's working on ios unfortunately. I'm getting error: Unsupported dashed / dotted border style
